# How to add image field in form drupal 7

Tags: php, image, drupal-7

i am creating a form as shown in image which saves detail in csv in background by putting php code in body block which works fine but can anyone tell me how to add the image upload option in form and to save the same in other place

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First do not add code in body block. Create a custom module.

To add image field please refer [Drupal Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file).

Eg.

```
$form['image_example_image_fid'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#description' => t('The uploaded image will be displayed on this page using the image style choosen below.'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('image_example_image_fid', ''),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
);
```

Comment: great.thanks a lot for commenting .i will go ahead with this hoping that we can add text fields as shown in image also.Is it fine?

Comment: with Form API you can do/add anything. ;-)